# javascript to add 2 numbers in textboxes in asp.net, doesnt work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, onblur

this is my javascript to get addition of 2 values from 2 textboxes into the third....

its not working...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculate(ctrl1, ctrl2, ctrl3) {

        var c1 = document.getElementById(ctrl1);
        var c2 = document.getElementById(ctrl2);
        var c3 = document.getElementById(ctrl3);

        if (c1 != null && c2 != null & c3 != null) {
            c3.value = Number(c1.value) + Number(c2.value);

        }
        document.forms[0].txteanum.focus();

    }    
</script>
```

in textboxes

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" onblur='javascript:calculate("txtQuantity","txtRate","TxtAmount")'></asp:TextBox>
```

check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624756/1445836

Comment: Is the capital "T" in `"TxtAmount"` a typo? (You have lower-case "t" in the other fields.) If you View Source in the browser are those ids the ones actually produced from the ASP code?

Comment: could you write an else part and put an alert / console.log to find if any of those textboxes are null?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/r3SvQ so I assume what I mentioned in the previous comment is the problem. Try adding a `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute to your inputs...

Comment: See @hasanchuck's answer - you are using server side controls and their IDs may not be what you expect.

Comment: got my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11624756/1445836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the java script   which worked for me

```
function Sum() {
                        var text1 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
                        var text2 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>');
                        if (text1.value.length == 0 || text2.value.length == 0) {
                                alert('Textbox1 and Textbox2 should not be empty');
                                return;
                        }

                        var x = parseInt(text1.value);
                        var y = parseInt(text2.value);
                        document.getElementById('<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>').value = x +y;
                }
```

into the textboxes in .aspx page itself

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="Sum()"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onblur="Sum()"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct: `if (c1 != null && c2 != null & c3 != null)`

TO: `if (c1 != null && c2 != null && c3 != null)` Missing `&`

To commenters: Sorry I never heard of Number(), since I usually don't work with front-end (especially math in front-end), mostly PHP/C#.

Also, `c2`, `c3` are `<input>`'s ?

Comment: Good catch on the `&`, except that it doesn't actually matter: http://jsfiddle.net/r3SvQ/

Comment: @GuyDavid: +1 on the & catch. Also, it would be better if OP uses `ClientIDMode="Static"`. It might be a case of ID mangling.

Comment: Effectively the operands are converted to numbers such that in practice `true & true` returns `1` and `true & false` or other combinations with `false` return `0`. See [Bitwise logical operators at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_logical_operators).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe You can't get textboxes. Have you tried to give them clientidmode static?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" onblur='javascript:calculate("txtQuantity","txtRate","TxtAmount")' ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```